# Javascript clicking one of multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

There are two buttons present in a form, and I would like to use GreaseMonkey to automatically click one of the buttons when the page loads. The two buttons are:

```
<td rowspan="2"><input class="first action" name="first" type="submit" value="First Action" style="font-size: 10pt;" /></td>
<td rowspan="2"><input class="second action" name="second" type="submit" value="Second Action" style="font-size: 10pt;" /></td>
```

I have tried the two below codes, but neither are working. The first selects the form and tries to submit it, and I get an error that says "No Action Permitted." The second tries to click() the button.

First:

```
var button = document.getElementById('units_form');
window.location(button);
```

Second:

```
var button = document.getElementByClassName('first action');
button.click();
```

Comment: the second one has a syntax error, which you'd have seen if you'd bothered checking your browser console. `getElement(s)ByClassName`. It's Elements PLURAL, not singular.

Comment: Element can be with or without an s, correct? It does not work either way.

Comment: no. it can't. it's singular for "byID" because a dom ID **MUST** be unique. but there can be mutiple elements with the same class, so the function's plural as well.

Comment: Makes since. Thanks. But after that correct, it still does not work.

Comment: geBClassName also returns an array of results, not a single dom node. you can't click on the array. try `button[0].click`, but first do `console.log(button)` to see what you DID get back.

Comment: I'm on Firefox on the Mac, and I did as suggested and nothing showed in the console tab. However, I changed the code and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the generic solution:

- to get an element object by class name, use `document.getElementsByName("class_name")[0]`. The last part `[0]` gives you the first of all elements that have this class
- To fire an event on element, see [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). I strongly advise to **read it all**. Judging from your post you're quite lazy when it comes to reading articles.

Putting it all together:

```
var button_element = document.getElementsByName("button-class-name")[0];
var event_object = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
});
button_element.dispatchEvent(event_object);
```

Also, most sites use jQuery library, for which it boils down to:

```
$(".class_name").click();
```

Note that this will fire on all elements with that class name.